# Sort column ascending but I want 0 to come last and RANDOMLY using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, random-data

I need to get data from MySQL table in ascending order but zero values come last and **randomly**

Right now this is my order by condition.This is not working

```
ORDER BY sortorder=0 RAND(),sortorder
```

Comment: This question will marked as low quality. Please provide more information. Help us to help you.

Comment: Hmm. No code, no sample data no actual output - nothing to go on

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional ordering

```
select *
from table
order by column > 0 desc, column asc, rand()
```

Add rand() at the end

[Demo](http://rextester.com/EAFJD59480)

Or you could use `union`

```
(select * from table where column > 0 order by column asc)
union all
(select * from table where column = 0 order by rand())
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/QPZHVI38046)

Comment: i need zero column value data randomly

Comment: I need 0 value data only  come last and randomly.In that demo complete data showing randomly

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data from mysql randomly and zero values come last. You may want to try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY `column` = 0, rand();
```

Comment: I need Zero value data only randomly

Comment: Not complete data randomly

Comment: then add where condition where column = 0

Comment: I have zero value data and other data also.Zero value data should come last and randomly

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table where column = 0 ORDER BY `column` = 0, rand();`

Comment: by using above code will get column` = 0 values only

Comment: If you remove the where condition then the query will get all data and zero value data will come in the last randomly

Comment: Then complete data will get randomly.I need 0 values only randomly.rest all asc order